# How to repeat an action all the time in Swift 3 with SK?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm doing a game in `Swift 3` with `SpriteKit` and I want to repeat an action all the time and I'm not able to do it.

I want to repeat the action in the `didMoveToView` function. In Swift 2 will be something like this:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    ...
    runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence
    ([SKAction.runBlock(spawnEnemy), SKAcion.waitForDuration(2.5)])))
    ...
}
```

Note that the action what I want to repeat is `spawnEnemy()`. I tried to use the new functions that implements Swift 3 to do it but it wasn't possible to execute.

How I should do it?

Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is still possible in Swift 3. Some of the naming has changed slightly.

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.run(spawnEnemy), SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2.5)])))
}
```